# Sketch the set $\{z||z-2|>|z-3|\}$ in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors, locus

Draft the set $\{z||z-2|>|z-3|\}$ in the complex plane. What I did is: 
$\{z|\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}>\sqrt{(x-3)^2+y^2}\}=\{z|(x-2)^2>(x-3)^2\}=\{z|x>2.5\}$. 
Now how is such a set "sketched"? It really seems to me like a Locus but I haven't practiced it since I graduated High-School and now I was given it after the first lecture with no background regarding Sketching. Do I simply mark the entire right side of the Axis system? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that $(x-2)^2\lt (x-3)^2\iff x\color{red}{\lt} 2.5$

Comment: You're right. In the original question it was ">". I'll edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$ such that $x>2.5$

So you can color the region right side of the line $x=2.5$ excluding the line.

Comment: So I color the part, and mark this line red or something?

Comment: No use a dotted line. Rather than a colored line